# How to display a checkbox boolean value in a data preview in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, events, checkbox

I'm trying to set up a checkbox in React so that it would display a boolean (`true`/`false` or `checked`/`unchecked`) in a data preview box. I couldn't make it work yet.

I guess my `onChange` event is not right (`handleOnChangeAgreementCheckbox`). How do I fix that?

#### [Demo on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-butterfly-oveqq)

#### Code

```
          <Input
            name="eligibleAge"
            type="checkbox"
            label="I agree"
            checked={this.state.active}
            value={this.state.checked}
            onChange={(e) => {
              this.handleOnChangeAgreementCheckbox({
                target: {
                  name: e.target.name,
                  value: e.target.checked,
                },
              });
            }}
          />
```

#### Desired Output in Data Preview:

```
    "eligibleAge": true
```

or

```
    "eligibleAge": "checked"
```

(Thanks! I'm new to React framework.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be using the wrong component for your checkbox. Try this:

Change this line:

```
import { Input, Button } from "react-advanced-form-addons";
```

to:

```
import { Input, Button, Checkbox } from "react-advanced-form-addons";
```

And then change your checkbox render code from this:

```
<Input
  name="eligibleAge"
  type="checkbox"
  label="I agree"
  checked={this.state.active}
  value={this.state.checked}
  onClick={() => this.handleOnChangeAgreementCheckbox()}
/>
```

to this:

```
<Checkbox
  name="eligibleAge"
  label="I agree"
  checked={this.state.eligible}
/>
```

Comment: @Emma I took another shot at this and updated my answer with a solution. Let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I will use your input as example:

```
            name="eligibleAge"
            type="checkbox"
            label="I agree"
            checked={this.state.active}
            value={this.state.checked}
            onClick={() => this.handleOnChangeAgreementCheckbox()}
          />
```

handleOnChangeAgreementCheckbox function:

```
handleOnChangeAgreementCheckbox = (e) => {
 this.setState({
  eligibleAge: e.target.value
 })
}
```

And you can use `this.state.eligibleAge` to shoe true/false